# I lost my p12 certificate file of iOS how should i get that?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I made the IOS app using PhoneGap Build its working fine.. but now i wanted to release an update for my previous application on apple store. I have provisioning profile certificate which i can get from apple developer account easily which is being used before for my previous application. but my pc get formatted after that i lost my all keys which is in keychain acess. How should i get that p12 file which is associated with my provisioning profile now. which is needed to build the app and to update on apple store. plz help mi out from this..

Answer (score 5):

You can't. If you lost your private key (part of the p12) you will need to create a profile certificate.

Comment: So i have to create new provisioning profile? And i can not update my application on apple store?

Comment: Yes you can just create a new certificate. Then update you provisioning profile to use this certificate and update your by signing it with the updated profile.

Comment: so this should allow mi to update it with my previous application ? or have to create separate application on apple store?

Comment: No you can just update your previous app. Certificates are only valid for one year thus every year you will need to update you certificates. If would be a weird if after doing this you could update your app.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to create new distribution certificates and provisioning profile**

Go to developer portal,
Revoke your current distribution certificate *(whose p12/private key lost)* It won't affect existing live app, Now wait a few seconds and refresh the page and you should see a button "Request Certificate". You'll have to follow the Certificate Signing Request instructions again and upload the .csr file. Create new certificate & download it and install in your Keychain Access app on your Mac. Export the .p12 from Keychain. Your Private key is ready.

Now, delete the existing distribution provisioning profile with old certs,
You'll have to create a new provisioning profile for the App, using the new certificate.

Uplaod the **new p12 and distribution provisioning profile** to phonegap console. Create IPA and Submit to iTunesConnect.
It worked for me, It will work for sure.

Comment: Hi, I have many private keys in Keychain, how do I know which one is the right one?